# Internal Error when starting up Gallio testrunner from Nant scripts

Tags: nant, watin, mbunit, gallio

When Gallio starts up to start running our regression test with watiN, I get the following error:

```
           [gallio] Gallio NAnt Task - Version 3.2 build 744
           [gallio] Start time: 1:07 PM
           [gallio] Stop time: 1:07 PM (Total execution time: 0.285 seconds)


        BUILD FAILED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 2 warning(s)

        INTERNAL ERROR

        System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Gallio.Runner.Projects.DefaultTestProjectManager' to type 'Gallio.Runner.Projects.ITestProjectManager'. at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.RegistryServiceLocator.Resolve[TService]() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnitv3.2\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\Extensibility\RegistryServiceLocator.cs:line 52 at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.RunWithRuntime() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.2\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runner\TestLauncher.cs:line 513 at Gallio.Runner.TestLauncher.Run() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnitv3.2\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runner\TestLauncher.cs:line 480 at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.RunLauncher(TestLauncher launcher)
           at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.InternalExecute()
           at Gallio.NAntTasks.GallioTask.ExecuteTask()
           at NAnt.Core.Task.Execute()
           at NAnt.Core.Target.Execute()
           at NAnt.Core.Project.Execute(String targetName, Boolean forceDependencies)
```

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Gallio 3.3.1.